# Background not changing back to original

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to change the background of the .search-toggle div when .search-container is visible and then i want it to return to its original background image.

The issue i am having is that it is not returning to the original image.

I have set up a fiddle using background-color rather than background-image.

Please could you enlighten me on how i could amend the JQuery code to ensure this happens. if you have time an explanation would be appreciated also as i'm quite new to JQuery and any help is appreciated.

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/wnGJM/1/

Here is the code:

```
var speed = 500;
    $('#search-toggle').on('click', function(){

        var $$ = $(this),
            panelWidth = $('#search-container').outerWidth();

        if( $$.is('.myButton') ){
            $('#search-container').animate({right:0}, speed);
            $$.removeClass('myButton')
        } else {
            $('#search-container').animate({right:-panelWidth}, speed);
            $$.addClass('myButton')
        }

        if($(this).is(':visible')){
           $('#search-toggle').css("background-image", "url(images/close-icon.png)");
        } else {
           $('#search-toggle').css("background-image", "url(images/search-icon.png)");
        }

    });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element is always visible. You can suppress that last `if` statement and use your actual logic block:

### [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wnGJM/5/)

```
  var speed = 500;
  $('#search-toggle').on('click', function () {
      var $$ = $(this),
          panelWidth = $('#search-container').outerWidth();

      if ($$.is('.myButton')) {
          $('#search-container').animate({
              right: 0
          }, speed);
          $$.removeClass('myButton');
          $$.css("background-color", "#0F0");
      } else {
          $('#search-container').animate({
              right: -panelWidth
          }, speed);
          $$.addClass('myButton');
          $$.css("background-color", "#000");
      }
  });
```

For your actual code, just replace the `background-color` parts with whatever applies to this case.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that you can do this with CSS trantitions and only use js to toggle a class ?

```
$('#search-toggle').on('click', function(){
    $('body').toggleClass('active');
});
```

(*i am using `body` just for illustration.. any common parent would work*)

and adding `transition:all 0.5s;` to your css rule of the animating element..

```
.active #search-toggle{
    background-color:#0F0;
}
.active #search-container{
    right:0px;
}
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/wnGJM/6/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using position to show and hide search container `.is(':visible')` will always be true and also in your case `$(this)` is a reference to #search-toggle, not #search-container, which is also always visible. It would be easier to just use the if statement where you show/hide the search-container. There you can also change the background of the search-toggle

http://jsfiddle.net/wnGJM/3/

```
var speed = 500;
$('#search-toggle').on('click', function(){
    var $$ = $(this),
        panelWidth = $('#search-container').outerWidth();
    if( $$.is('.myButton') ){
        $('#search-container').animate({right:0}, speed);
        $$.removeClass('myButton').css("background-color", "#0F0");
    } else {
        $('#search-container').animate({right:-panelWidth}, speed);
        $$.addClass('myButton').css("background-color", "#000");
    }
});
```